# What is the difference between "The man pulled on the fishing rod" and "The man pulled at the fishing rod" and "The man pulled the fishing rod"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I can't imagine what the actions of "**pull on something**" and "**pull at something**" were?

What is the difference between "**The man pulled on the fishing rod**" and "**The man pulled at the fishing rod**" and "**The man pulled the fishing rod**"?

Comment: See [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%20on#:~:text=Definition%20of%20pull%20on,forth%2C%20pulling%20on%20his%20pipe.). I would use _pull on_ for pulling a cord or handle that you expect to operate something (like a bell rope), _pull at_ for tugging something repeatedly, like a child _pulling on_ its mother's skirts to attract her attention.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said _pulling at_ her skirts!